# Load data from one oracle database table to another oracle database table

Tags: database, oracle

I want to load data from one database table to another database table.
For example there exists table 'tbl' in db1 and db2 databases, and I want to copy all data from 'tbl' of 'db1' to 'tbl' of 'db2' in oracle.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you really mean different databases, or do you do mean different schema on the same database?

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of either [exp/imp](http://wiki.oracle.com/page/Oracle+export+and+import+) or [expdp/impdp](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/OracleDataPump10g.php) (10g+) for this.

The older exp/imp command is slower, but has the advantage that the export file is created and read from the client system. The expdp/impdp command is much faster, but the file is created on and read from the server where the databases live. So, if you have your databases on different servers, you'll need to copy the export files around. Also, it requires an [Oracle Directory](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_directory) to be set up by the DBA.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this , you will need to create a database link between the two schemas. [Here](http://oracle-database-tips.com/oracle_database_link_tutorials.html) is a link to a tutorial that may help.

Comment: Thanks for the above link, but following the steps that the link gives I am able to create a database link but while trying to access the link for suppose retrieving data error comes for databse link name stating "could not resolve service name"